# How to implement a function in Java that returns the hierarchy of an employee inside a company

Tags: java, recursion, tree, hierarchy

I am given an Employee-class and a List which contains all employees of a company. Now, I want to implement a function `findHierarchy(Employee employee)` which returns the hierarchy of the corresponding employee.

I.e. imagine the following hierarchy tree:

```
boss
    department_leader_1
        group_leader_a
            employee_group_a_1
            employee_group_a_2
        group_leader_b
            employee_group_b_1
    department_leader_2
```

`findHierarchy(boss)` should return `3`, whereas `findHierarchy(employee_group_a_1)` should return `0` and `findHierarchy(group_leader_a)` should return `1`.

I have already implemented a function `findSubordinates(Employee employee, List<employee> allEmployees)` which returns a list with all the direct subordinates of a given employee. For example `findSubordinates(group_leader_a, allEmployees)` would return `[ employee_group_a_1, employee_group_a_2 ]` and `findSubordinates(department_leader_1, allEmployees)` would return `[group_leader_a, group_leader_b]`.

Here is my guess as on how to implement `findHierarchy()`:

```
public static int findHierarchy(Employee employee, List<Employee> allEmployees, int hierarchy) {

        List<Employee> subordinates = findSubordinates(employee, allEmployees);
        
        if (subordinates.size() > 0) {
            hierarchy += 1;
            for (Employee subordinate: subordinates) {
                hierarchy = findHierarchy(subordinate, allEmployees, hierarchy);
            }
        } 
        return hierarchy;
    }
```

This doesn't seem to be too far off. However, I have troubles thinking about this recursion completely. Does anyone see where the mistake could be?

Comment: The `hierarchy = findHierarchy(subordinate, ...`  bit looks wrong. You want to be calculating a maximum. i.e. boss's position is 3 because `department_leader_1`'s position is 2. In calculating the boss's position, `department_leader_2`'s position is irrelevant. The logic needs to reflect that.

Comment: Right, the current code only finds the hierarchy of the last subordinate in the list.  There's no iteration here because every value gets overwritten except the last one.  Taking a maximum of the returned values makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to replace

```
hierarchy += 1;
for (Employee subordinate: subordinates) {
     hierarchy = findHierarchy(subordinate, allEmployees, hierarchy);
}
```

with

```
int currentHierarchy = hierarchy;                 
for (Employee subordinate: subordinates) {
    hierarchy = Math.max(findHierarchy(subordinate, allEmployees, currentHierarchy + 1), hierarchy);
}
```

Math.max is required to prevent a case with overwritting previous long Employee chain with a shorter one

Comment: Thx a lot, man, this seems to do the trick! ... I still wonder how an old long Employee chain can be overwritten with a shorter one, but think this is just because recursion is really hard for me to think about... it would probably even happen for the example that I have given: because department_leader_2 doesn't have any further subordinates, the final result is only 2, while it should be 4. Does this make sense?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem lies in this line right here:

```
hierarchy = findHierarchy(subordinate, allEmployees, hierarchy);
```

As you can see, you are first incrementing hierarchy by 1:

```
hierarchy += 1;
```

and then instantly resetting it in the for loop, instead of assigning it do:

```
hierarchy += findHierarchy(subordinate, allEmployees, hierarchy);
```

Comment: doing `+= findHierarchy` makes no sense. That makes the employee's hierarchy level equal to the *sum* all the subordinates. If somebody manages an employee with hierarchy level 1, 2, and 3 that means their own hierarchy is `1 + 2 + 3 = 6` rather than just `4` (one higher)

Comment: oh god, yeah i am dumb! Sorry, did not realize